# C++ Reading Long Non-delimited Integers, Separating Them and Putting into a 2d Array

Tags: c++, c, text, scanf

I have a *numbers.txt* with **m** lines containing **n**-digit integers:

```
185793290584395734589340920932
432904895929583224024902234023
```

I have tried using **fscanf()** but am having trouble defining the **format** (more information [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/)).

```
    FILE *fid;
fid = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
int numbers[m][n];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        int num;
        fscanf(fid,format,&num);
        numbers[i][j] = num;
    }
}
```

Similar questions users have asked in the past seem to involve delimited data, whereas mine is not.

I would like to be able to get a 2d array of the form:
*numbers*=

```
1 8 5 7 9 3 2 9 0 5 8 4 3 9 5 7 3 4 5 8 9 3 4 0 9 2 0 9 3 2
4 3 2 9 0 4 8 9 5 9 2 9 5 8 3 2 2 4 0 2 4 9 0 2 2 3 4 0 2 3
```

Comment: @Duck, I don't think he wants to print it out. I think A.L. wants to store the 2D array and calculate on it.

Comment: Is this C or C++? There are ways of solving this issue that are specific to both languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `fgetc`

```
FILE *fid = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
int numbers[m][n];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        numbers[i][j] = fgetc(fid) - '0';
    }
    fgetc(fid); // throw away new line
}
```

or with `fscanf`

```
FILE *fid = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
int numbers[m][n];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    char c[n + 1];  //an extra char for '\0'
    fscanf(fid, "%s", c);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        numbers[i][j] = c[j] - '0';
    }
}
```

Comment: What does **- '0'** do?

Comment: @A.L, you are reading a `char`. The character `'0'` is `48`, the character `'A'` is `65`, etc. Subtracting `'0'` translates the character `'0'` (`48`) to the integer value `0`, the character `'1'` (`49`) to the integer value `1`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing each digit in each index of the array? If yes, you can use "%c", and then substract it with '0'.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
fscanf(fid, "%1d", &num);
```